# PGFplots: Vertical line attached to x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, node-connections, axis, vertical

I want to plot a small vertical line from y = 0 on certain x coordinates, connected to a node. However, the vertical line does not stick/connect correctly to the x-axis.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
        \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

     \begin{document}
                \begin{landscape}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                             \begin{axis}[
                                  width=1.15\textwidth,
                                  height=0.80\textheight,
                                  scale only axis,
                                  xmin=-9,xmax=45,
                                  ymin=0,ymax=2200,
                                  axis y line*=left,
                                  xlabel={x axis},
                                  ylabel={y axis}]

                                  %Step sections
                                  \node[rotate=90,right] (s2) at (axis cs: -6.86,100){\tiny{NODE 0}};
                                  \node(d2) at (axis cs:-6.86,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
                                  \draw(s2)--(d2);
                                  \node[rotate=90,right] (s3) at (axis cs: 0,100){\tiny{NODE 1}};
                                  \node(d3) at (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
                                  \draw(s3)--(d3);
                                  \node[rotate=90,right] (s6) at (axis cs: 31.4,100){\tiny{NODE 2}};
                                  \node(d6) at (axis cs:31.4,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
                                  \draw(s6)--(d6);
                               \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}
                    \end{landscape}
       \end{document}
```

[image: See below for a impression:]

Comment: Basically, a `node` has a size, even if it doesn't have content, and when you draw a line to a `node`, the line terminates at the border of the node. For a case like this you should use `\coordinate (foo) at (x,y);` instead of a normal `\node`. Note also that `\tiny` is not a macro that takes an argument (like e.g. `\textbf{bold}`), it is a switch which influences all the following text in the same scope. To limit the effect you should thus use `{\tiny ..}`, not `\tiny{..}`, but inside a `\node` you can leave out the braces altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better idea to draw the lines first with the exact dimensions you want and then place on their "rotated right" the text you want:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
             width=1.15\textwidth,
             height=0.80\textheight,
             scale only axis,
             xmin=-9,xmax=45,
             ymin=0,ymax=2200,
             axis y line*=left,
            xlabel={x axis},
            ylabel={y axis}]

            %Step sections
            \draw (axis cs: -6.86,0)--(axis cs:-6.86,100) coordinate (s2);
            \node[rotate=90,right]at (s2) {\tiny NODE 0 };
           \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{landscape}
   \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Notice that I used coordinate to name the above point. Now... all this can me
replaced by one instead of two commands:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

 \begin{document}
            \begin{landscape}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                         \begin{axis}[
                              width=1.15\textwidth,
                              height=0.80\textheight,
                              scale only axis,
                              xmin=-9,xmax=45,
                              ymin=0,ymax=2200,
                              axis y line*=left,
                              xlabel={x axis},
                              ylabel={y axis}]

                           %Step sections
                           \draw (axis cs: -6.86,0)--(axis cs:-6.86,100) node[rotate=90,right] {\tiny NODE 0 };
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{landscape}
   \end{document}
```

Used node this time. Same output.

Answer (score 3):

The main "fault" was that you just used a `\node` as starting point and thus, when you draw a line from that node it is used an appropriate "outer anchor" of that node to draw the line (which is normally the desired behavior. To make this visible add `draw` to one of the `\node` options and maybe in addition some text in that `\node`, i.e. write something in the empty curly brackets `{}`).

There are two possible simple solutions if you want to stick to your solution. Either add `coordinate` to the `\node` options or add `.center` to the `(d...)` coordinate in your `draw` command, e.g. write `\draw(s2)--(d2.center);`.

But here I present another solution. I create a custom style `Pin` for `pin` and modify it to your needs. Then it can easily be used with a minimum of code to write for that `Pin`s.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher so TikZ coordinates don't have to be
        % prefixed by `axis cs:'
        compat=1.11,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % create a style to draw the annotations
    Pin/.style={
        % we need only a coordinate as a "base node"
        coordinate,
        % then we draw a pin to the "base node" using the following options
        pin={[%
                pin distance=4ex,
                pin edge={
                    draw=black,
                    thin,
                },
                node font=\tiny,
            ]above:{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}%
        },
    },
]
    \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        xmin=-9,xmax=45,
        ymin=0,ymax=2200,
        xlabel={x axis},
        ylabel={y axis},
    ]
        %Step sections
        \node [Pin=NODE 0] at (-6.86,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
        \node [Pin=NODE 1] at ( 0   ,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
        \node [Pin=NODE 2] at (31.4 ,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]